# How to check if a bool from a struct has been altered to false or if it was already false

Tags: go, boolean, go-gorm

```
type user_account struct {
ID                 string `sql:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
Gender_Identity_id string `sql:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
Email              string
Name               string
LastName           string
Password           string
BirthDate          string `sql:"type:date;default:current_time"`
AssignedSex        bool
Show               bool
Sleep              bool
Disabled           bool
}
```

**If you send a user_account object without setting the sleep value to true , the value will be false automatically i need to know if the value was actualy set as false or if its false Because it hasn't been set**

```
func UpdateUser(userUpdate user_account) {

db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=06maneco dbname=HookTest sslmode=disable")
var user user_account

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {

    db.Where("id = ?", userUpdate.ID).First(&user)
    if userUpdate.Name != user.Name {
        user.Name = userUpdate.Name
    } else if userUpdate.Password != "" {
        user.Password = userUpdate.Password
    } else if userUpdate.Gender_Identity_id != "" {
        user.Gender_Identity_id = userUpdate.Gender_Identity_id
    } else if userUpdate.Email != "" {
        user.Email = userUpdate.Email
    } else if userUpdate.Show != user.Show {
        user.Show = userUpdate.Show
    }
    db.Save(&user)

}
```

Comment: Where is this coming from? You say "If you send a user_account object" - sent from where? How? In what format?

Comment: `false` is `false`, you can't differentiate between the two. Are you sure you can't use a `*bool`?

Comment: Either avoid making that decision based on the value of a bool in the struct, or use a pointer and check whether it's nil.

Comment: This is a REST API. user_account will be handled by an endpoint. I'm struggling with how to detect if, for example, I received a "{name: 'username', 'show: false}" through POST. Go will convert it to a  user_account struct with show = false. But if I receive a "{name: 'username'}", the user_account struct will also have a show = false. Do you guys get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `Sleep` field you can use a pointer which can be also a nil:

```
type userAccount struct {
    Sleep *bool
}
```

Now you can check it:

```
func check(u userAccount) {
    if u.Sleep == nil {
        // not set
    } else if !(*u.Sleep) {
        // set to false
    } else {
        // set to true
    }
}
```

Check it in the Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8EIs_yIC0mw.

Comment: thas a great idea but if i try to store a value in the sleep field , it wont work it sayst Cannot use true (type bool) as type *boo

Comment: @LeonardoAndrigo please, look at the playground link, I've updated it to show you different ways of setting the *bool field, you should **point** to some variable

Comment: @hsrv thaks it helped  a lot